# INDEX MATCH with COUNTIF only finds first 3 unique values then stops

Tags: excel-formula

I have a long list with codes in sheet 1 of my data starting at A2 (the list is very long 4500 rows):

```
C56 
A125 
R89 
C56 
B125 
B125 
A125 
R89 
D512 
S226 
D512 
R89
```

In sheet 2 I need to create a list of all the codes and remove the duplicates. I'm using the following array formula to try and do it:

`{=INDEX('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$4568,MATCH(0,COUNTIF('Sheet 1'!$A$1:A1,'Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$4568),0))}`

The formula results in the 1st and 2nd unique codes to be returned correctly but the 3rd unique code is duplicated for the rest of the lines:

```
Code 
C56 
A125 
R89 
R89 
R89
```

I also tried `=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$4568,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF('Sheet 2'!$A$1:A1,'Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$4568&""),0),0))&"","")` as a non-array formula, but again I get the same result.

I can't work out what is wrong with either of these formulas.

Comment: The first argument of the CountIf needs to be the list you are now creating, in fact looking at it, it needs to be offset one cell above the list you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$4568,MATCH(0,COUNTIF('Sheet 1'!$B$1:B1,'Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$4568),0))`

Assuming your list starts in `B2`

(Array formula - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)